# insert arrays to mongoDB in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb

I am new to Python and mongoDB.

I have several arrays I want to insert to mongoDB.
my arrays describe movies. 
I want to write a function like this:

```
def insert_to_db(ids,release_dates,genres_ids,original_titles,titles,popularities,
vote_countes,vote_averages,languages,adult_bool):
```

where all the arguments to the function are vectors of movie attributes. 
I want to insert all of those attributes to a collection named "movies".
for example, the first document in the collection should be in this form:

```
{
  "id": the value of ids[0]
  "release_date": the value of release_dates[0]
  "genre" : the value of genre[0]
  etc.
  etc.
}
```

and so on and so on.

so I started to write something like this, to create the "movies" collection:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient()
client=MongoClient()
db=client["movies_db"]
collection=db["movies"]
```

and now I need to iteratively insert the fields from the vectors. 
any idea how to do this?

Comment: Next you need [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip),  [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-dict) and perhaps [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list)